# JSF 2.0 EL #{param.XXX} dynamic?

Tags: jsf, parameters

Is there a way to fetch params in the .xhtml dynamically?
the normal way would be: #{param.PARAMETERNAME}

now this PARAMETERNAME sometimes not certain and can change.

Is there a way to make e.g.:

## {param.#{id}}

i tried it with additional ui:param like

but #{param.paramname} doesn't work... (returns always null like it searches for the absolute "paramname")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The brace notation (`[]`) was introduced for this very reason. So, if you have a `paramName` parameter then the following will do the trick:

```
#{param[paramName]}
```